# Cannot open ssh connection between windows 10 and OS X with Bitvise ssh client

Tags: ssh, windows-10, osx-yosemite, parallels

I need an sftp windows client and I just installed Bitvise. My windows 10 version runs on Parallels (version 10) on a Mac (OS X Yosemite version 10.10.5). As a test, I tried to open an ssh connection with the Bitvise client to the ssh server running on the Mac. I first went to the Mac, System Preferences -> Sharing and clicked on File Sharing and Remote Login (for all users, just to be sure). I can perfectly ping the Mac from Windows as well. Now when I try to open a connection from Windows to the Mac (Bitvise GUI or simply sftp from the command line), invariably I get this message.

**The SSH2 session has terminated with error. Reason: Error class: LocalSshDisconn, code: ConnectionLost, message: FlowSshTransport: received EOF.**

Does anybody knows what's going on? I couldn't find that error message anywhere. Just for your info I tried this from the command line

> sftp mymacuser@my.mac.ip.address

And then again

> ping my.mac.ip.address

works perfectly OK.

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Did you check  inbound and outbound connections over port 22 on both machines?

Comment: No and I don't know how to do it

Comment: Also, you are trying to connect between your machines inside a lan, right?...you don't have a public ip, right?...I case that you have an public ip on your osx machine, you can use this tool to check connectivity: http://www.infobyip.com/sshservertest.php

Comment: You're right. I'm in a LAN and neither the windows virtual machine nor the OS X machine have a public IP address.

Comment: The problem seems to be on the client side, because I could connect to the OS X machine with the ssh client of another Mac in the same LAN.

Comment: From the Windows side...are you using a third party tool like `Putty` to connect to your osx machine?...also did you have an antivirus running in your windows machine(if so, try to turn it off and try to connect)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126640/discussion-between-hackerman-and-edd).

Comment: I am not using putty (actually I was thinking about it but I only saw ssh, but neither sftp nor scp) that's why I picked Bitvise. Maybe I was wrong about putty. At any rate, I'll turn off the antivirus and see what happens

Comment: Ok...just for the record, for ssh and sftp on windows, I use MobaXTerm(the portable edition) :)

Comment: Hi Hackerman. In the end I could get around the whole thing using the ssh client on OS X. Thanks though